# Dynamically creating spreadsheet menu items

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, menuitem

I am trying to create a dynamically populated menu in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script.

1. I have a sheet, 'Classes', where I list the classes I teach.
2. On running my script I get my script to read and load these classes into an array.
3. In order to only hard-code values in the original 'Classes' sheet I want to then to create a sub-menu item for each of these classes.

The sheet is called 'Classes'.
The values in the classes sheet are 8H, 9p1, 9p2 etc.
They are in cells A1:A12.
In the debugger the array, menuItemArray, loads correctly with all expected classes from the 'Classes' sheet.

The error I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot find function addSubMenu in object 9p1. (line 13,
>   file "Code")

This is when stepping into the line

```
menuItemArrayClass =  menuItemArray [menuCount]
```

I would be really grateful for any help as to what I am doing wrong or any better ways to do it.

Here is my code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var menuCount = 0; 
    ui.createMenu('Manage Timetable')
    .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
    .addSeparator()

    var menuItemArray =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Classes').getDataRange().getValues();  
    for (menuCount=1;menuCount < menuItemArray.length;++menuCount) {
        var menuItemArrayClass = [] 
        menuItemArrayClass =  menuItemArray [menuCount]
        .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Manage Classes')
            .addItem(menuItemArrayClass [menuCount] + 'Schedule Timetable', 'runBatch1'))
        .addToUi();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Many thanks  Akshin I will give that a try, thanks, Simon

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383424/

Answer (score 12):

- You want to create custom menu.
- You want to update the custom functions by editing the Spreadsheet.
- You want to use one function name like `myFunction()` for several functions in the custom menu.
- You want to give each value to the function as the argument when a function is run from the custom menu.
- The sample situation is as follows.

  - There are values in the column "A" to "I".
  - There are 9 functions in the custom menu. The custom menu is created when the Spreadsheet is opened. The function names are corresponding to each column name.
  - When the function of the column "A" is clicked, the values of the column "A" is activated.
  - When the column "I" is copied to the column "H", the new function is added to the custom menu.

I understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, when a function is added to the custom menu with `addItem` method, the argument cannot been able to be used. And when one of functions in the custom menu is run, the information about the function name which was run cannot be retrieved. By this, your goal cannot be directly achieved. So it is required to use the workaround.

When I saw your question, for your goal, I thought that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59386046/7108653) is useful. At google.script.run, it is required to be able to directly run the function at the script editor and the function is included in `this`. But at the custom menu, when the function is included in `this`, the function can be run even when the function cannot be directly run at the script editor. When the function is run in only GAS side, the function can be run even when the function cannot be directly run with the script editor. I thought that this situation can be used for the workaround.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified by including this workaround, it becomes as follows. Please copy and paste it to the container-bound script of Spreadsheet which has the headers ("Col1", "Col2",,,) at the 1st row and the values from 2nd row. And when you run the script, please open the Spreadsheet. By this, the custom menu is added. And when new column is added by copying, the additional column is also added to the custom menu. And when the function at the custom menu is run, the values corresponding to the column are activated.

#### From:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
  .addSeparator();
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Sub-menu');
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    var dynamicMenu = headers[i];
    subMenu.addItem(dynamicMenu,'dynamicItem');
  }
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function menuItem1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
}

function dynamicItem() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .alert('You clicked the dynamic menu item!');
}
```

#### To:

```
function installFunctions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
  .addSeparator();
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Sub-menu');
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    var dynamicMenu = headers[i];
    this[dynamicMenu] = dynamicItem(i); // Added
    subMenu.addItem(dynamicMenu,dynamicMenu); // Modified
  }
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}

function dynamicItem(i) { // Added
  return function() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(2, i + 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).activate();
  }
}

installFunctions(); // Added

function onOpen() {} // Modified: This can be used as the simple trigger.

function onEdit() {} // Modified: This can be used as the simple trigger.

function onChange() {} // Added: Please install OnChange event trigger to this function.
```

- Before you use this script, please install the OnChange event trigger to the function of `onChange()`. By this, when the column is deleted, the custom menu is updated.
- The functions of `function onEdit() {}` and `function onChange() {}` are used for running `onOpen();`.

### Result:

[image]

### Note:

- In order to dynamically create the custom menu, this script is required to be run at initial stage when the function is run. So it is required to be put it as the global like `onOpen();`.
- In this workaround, when the function is run, `onOpen` is run every time. So when the number of columns are large, the process cost will be high. So please be careful this.
- This is a simple sample script for explaining one methodology of the workaround. So please modify this for your situation.

### References:

- [Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Different output in 3 anonymous function in GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59386046/7108653)

  - I think that this thread was useful for thinking OP's goal.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria I updated the script. Because I noticed that when the Spreadsheet is opened, `onOpen()` is run 2 times. So I modified this. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I've been experimenting with your solution, but can't reproduce. As soon as I leave the "onOpen" function, the global dynamic functions (this[dynamicMenu]) are lost.
The menu runs in another context where apparently only global static functions are recognised.

Comment: @Atmadata Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information for replicating your issue. By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.
Can you post link to this spreadsheet so I can see how it works?
I also added to this feature request:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753036

Comment: @Atmadata *As soon as I leave the "onOpen" function, the global dynamic functions (this[dynamicMenu]) are lost.* I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384141)  explains/solves your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var menuCount = 0; 
   var menu = ui.createMenu('Manage Timetable');
    menu.addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
    menu.addSeparator()

    var menuItemArray =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Лист2').getDataRange().getValues();  
    for (menuCount=0;menuCount < menuItemArray.length;menuCount++) {
        var menuItemArrayClass = [] 
        menuItemArrayClass =  menuItemArray [menuCount];
        menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Manage Classes')
            .addItem(menuItemArrayClass + ' Schedule Timetable', 'runBatch1'))
        menu.addToUi();
    }     
}
```

If you start from 1 you loose first row, so I changed it to 0.

Also now you need to dynamically allocate the scripts, but I do no know how they are set up in your sheet, so I left that part unchanged.

Also not sure if you need to add 'Manage Classes' menu every time, but I kept it just in case.

Try this instead as it seems more like what you want:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var menuCount = 0; 
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Manage Timetable')
  .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
  .addSeparator();
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Manage Classes');

  var menuItemArray =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Лист2').getDataRange().getValues();  
  for (menuCount=0;menuCount < menuItemArray.length;menuCount++) {
    var menuItemArrayClass = [] 
    menuItemArrayClass =  menuItemArray [menuCount];
    subMenu.addItem(menuItemArrayClass + ' Schedule Timetable', 'runBatch1');      
  }     

  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to assign dynamic `functionName`? Currently, I see **runBatch1** to be a static function against every dynamically generated menu item.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria You can pass any string that represents function name into `.addItem()`. Please see my answer for more details.

Comment: @Sourabh Choraria I would like to understand about your goal. 1. You want to add a function of the function name `myFunction` to the custom menu. 2. You want to run `myFunction` from the custom menu by giving the arguments. 3. The arguments are changed by the time. I could understand like this. But I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct. Can I ask you about the detail information of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike - to your 2nd point, yes. I'd like to be able to pass arguments in the function and more importantly, invoke a common function (that accepts arguments) as opposed to write more functions.

Comment: @Sourabh Choraria Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot still image your goal. In that case, when `myFunction` is run at the custom menu, how is the required arguments decided?

Comment: @Tanaike - check out some of my comments on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59374709/10713297) - can clarify further on email if that works too - I'm available at `code@script.gs`

Comment: @SourabhChoraria, what youa are asking is impposible as we cannot pass options to functions called with ".addItem". What you could do instead is make an html window with selection box that will then pass the selected value as option to your function. And this html box can then be run from the menu. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Sourabh Choraria Thank you for replying. From your explanation, I could understand about your goal. So I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to store the relevant captions and function names in Sheet1 columns A & B, respectively, you could simply call [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and iterate through that data.

```
/** 
 * SHEET1 VALUES
 * --------------------------------------
 *          Column A        Column B
 * Row 1    Class One       functionOne
 * Row 2    Class Two       functionTwo
 * Row 3    Class Three     functionThree
 */

function onOpen(e) {
  // Initialize the menu & submenu
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Menu Name').addItem('First label', 'menuItem1').addSeparator();
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Submenu Name');

  // Get the submenu item data from Sheet1
  // Values in column A represent the captions that will appear in the submenu
  // Values in column B represent the name of the function to be called
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A:B').getValues();
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < values.length; ++rowIndex) {
    var rowData = values[rowIndex];
    var caption = rowData[0]; // Column A value
    var functionName = rowData[1]; // Column B value
    if (caption != '' && functionName != '') { // Exclude empty strings
      subMenu.addItem(caption, functionName);
    }
  }     

  // Add the submenu to the menu, and finally to the UI
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() { Browser.msgBox('menuItem1'); }
function functionOne() { Browser.msgBox('functionOne'); }
function functionTwo() { Browser.msgBox('functionTwo'); }
function functionThree() { Browser.msgBox('functionThree'); }
```

---

In the original post, the error was happening because [`.addSubMenu()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu.html#addsubmenumenu) was being called on the value `[9p1]` instead of a [Menu object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu.html#additemcaption,-functionname). Further, from my understanding of the question, I think a menu *item* is intended to be created in the loop, not an individual submenu for each class. So those are two problems that needed to be resolved.

I also assume that you don't want to run `runBatch1` for every single menu item as that would defeat the purpose of creating different menu items. According to the  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu.html#addItem(String,String)), the method for adding a menu item expects two strings:

1. `caption` – The label for the menu item.
2. `functionName` – The name of the function to invoke when the user selects the item.

So it follows that you can substitute any string when making your `submenu.addItem()` call.

```
var caption = "Caption";
var functionName = "functionName";
var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Submenu Name');
subMenu.addItem(caption, functionName);
```

---

## Other Scenarios

### Array of Item Objects

Alternatively, you could define an array (or object map) of the various submenu items you want to include, rather than storing them in the spreadsheet. Here, I've used an array of objects to clearly define the caption & functionName values.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Initialize the menu & submenu
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Menu Name').addItem('First label', 'menuItem1').addSeparator();
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Submenu Name');

  // Array of items to include in the submenu
  var items = [
    { caption: 'Class One', functionName: 'functionOne' },
    { caption: 'Class Two', functionName: 'functionTwo' },
    { caption: 'Class Three', functionName: 'functionThree' }
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    var item = items[i];
    subMenu.addItem(item.caption, item.functionName);

  }     

  // Add the submenu to the menu, and finally to the UI
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() { Browser.msgBox('menuItem1'); }
function functionOne() { Browser.msgBox('functionOne'); }
function functionTwo() { Browser.msgBox('functionTwo'); }
function functionThree() { Browser.msgBox('functionThree'); }
```

### Caption String Manipulation

Since the method accepts any string, you can perform any string manipulation that will result in a valid function name. In this example,  I'm only storing the captions in an array and I dynamically generate the function names based on the caption values. (You could also pull the caption names from column A and apply the same manipulation.)

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Initialize the menu & submenu
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Menu Name').addItem('First label', 'menuItem1').addSeparator();
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Submenu Name');

  // Array of captions to include in the submenu.
  // Will generate function names from this.
  var captions = ['Class One', 'Class Two', 'Class Three'];
  for (var i = 0; i < captions.length; ++i) {
    var caption = captions[i];
    subMenu.addItem(caption, 'function' +  caption.split(' ')[1]);
  }     

  // Add the submenu to the menu, and finally to the UI
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() { Browser.msgBox('menuItem1'); }
function functionOne() { Browser.msgBox('functionOne'); }
function functionTwo() { Browser.msgBox('functionTwo'); }
function functionThree() { Browser.msgBox('functionThree'); }
```

Comment: Even with this approach, we'll need to first have created that many number of functions. What I was rather hoping for is that if we could pass that as a parameter within the function - ex: say, we had a common function - `myFunction(option)` where **option** would be a variable being passed at the time that dynamic function was being invoked. In this case, that could've been the variable `i` used in the `for` loop too.

Comment: Obviously, the `myFunction(option)` doesn't work as the `subMenu.addItem` expects a String,String input only.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria Unfortunately, you can't pass parameters into functions being called by custom menus.

Comment: I agree; another reason why I couldn't figure this out myself and was hoping for something a little more innovative or even a work around for having to run a common function with dynamic params being passed - a weird approach I could think of was if there were a function ID that the custom menu functions generated and if we could take that to decipher things further. Again, I couldn't figure the solution out myself and so thought to post a bounty on this question.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria Yeah, that's a different question than what you posted. If you have details about what you're trying to solve, you can post a question here on SO or in the [apps script community](https://groups.google.com/forum/?place=forum%2Fgoogle-apps-script-community#!forum/google-apps-script-community). A lot of the common cases can be resolved simply by using the [special methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods) available to bound scripts.