# Using a loop within the menu UI script beginner

Tags: dynamic, drop-down-menu, google-sheets

I am trying to create a dynamic menu that creates the names of the sheets in it. I dont often code and need some help. currently the code ON_Open creates a menu, creates its first item in the menu, then add a seperator and then goes into a loop. it checks how many sheets there are and starts at the first one. stores the name and makes a menu item with that name, then advances to the next sheet. gets its name and makes the next menu item. i can get the loop to work with the menu UI syntax.im not worried about the names. i will try to figure that out next,just want it to create the menus first

```
function onOpen() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numsheets = spreadsheet.getNumSheets();

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi
      .createMenu('SWMS CREATER')
      .addItem('Create New SWMS', 'showPrompt')
      .addSeparator()

 for ( var i = 0; i < numsheets.length;i++ ) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Test Menu');
    subMenu.addItem('Test script'i ,'showPrompt');
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP is trying to create a dynamic menu that lists each of the sheets in the spreadsheet. The OP's code is very close to working - there are just a small, but significant, number of adjustments.

```
function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('OPSWMS CREATER')
    .addItem('Create New SWMS', 'showPrompt')
    .addSeparator();

  var sheetList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('OPTest Menu');

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetList.length; i++) {
    subMenu.addItem(sheetList[i].getName(), 'showPrompt');
  }
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}
```

**Summary of major differences:**

1) variable `ui` moved out of the loop; and then re-used where possible.
2) variable `menu` established and also moved out of the loop. This is re-used to add the subMenu in the last line of code.
3) added a semi-colon after `.addSeparator()` (though optional)
4) used [`.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) to get all the sheets. **This is the first key element missing from the OP code**.
5) dropped `var numsheets` line. You don't need this because you can get the same count on `sheetList`.
6) within the loop, two things to note

- `sheetList[i]` the i in square brackets (`[i]`) returns the relevant item from "sheetList";
- [`.getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getname) returns the name of the sheet. Combined, `sheetList[i].getName()` gives you the name of the sheet, and lets you add it as a menu item selection.

7) `menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();` This add the contents of the loop to the menu. **This is the second key element missing from the OP code**.

**Credit**:
Akshin Jalilov's answer to [Google Apps Script: Dynamically creating spreadsheet menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539911/)