# Different output in 3 anonymous function in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a question.

In the [formal web page of google.script run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run?authuser=0#myFunction(...)), they saids that you can call "any server-side function" from client side using google.script.run.

In the below gs file, I defined function "hoge" using normal function expression.(the "this!" row)

If I execute this situation, output is randomly 1-4 numbers displayed on browser

By the way, I tried to change the define style of function "hoge". I created 3 pattern using anonymous function. (all are called from client side using "hoge(vv)")

1. `var hoge = function hoge(x){return x;};` (both side using "hoge" keyword) → then this worked same as normal function definition style.
2. `var hoge = function (x){return x;};` (only left using "hoge" keyword) → error
3. `var hogeNot = function hoge(x){return x;};` (only right using "hoge" keyword) → error

**Q. Why, "1" work well, but "2" is error.**

Thank you.

```
// gs file

var x;

function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("hello").evaluate(); // テンプレートオブジェクトの取得
}

function hoge(x){ // this!
  return x;
}
```

```
// html file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <p id="wi">hello</p>
    <script>
    function success(get){
      document.getElementById("wi").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<p>" + get + "</p>");
    }

    for (var v=1; v <= 4; ++v){ // aaを4回呼ぶ
      aa(v);
    }

    async function aa(vv){
      await google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).hoge(vv);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. Why, "1" work well, but "2" is error.

For this question, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Experiment:

At Google Apps Script, it seems that when the function can be recognized with the script editor and the function can be seen at `this`, the function can be directly run. For checking whether the function is included in `this`, the following script can be used.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var i in this) {
    if (i == "hoge") {
      Logger.log("%s, %s", i, typeof this[i])
    }
  }
}
```

#### About `var hoge = function hoge(x){return x;};`

In this case, the function of `hoge` can be seen at the script editor and this function can be directly run by the script editor. And also, above script returns `hoge, function`.

#### About `var hoge = function (x){return x;};`

In this case, the function of `hoge` cannot be seen at the script editor while above script returns `hoge, function`. And `hoge` cannot be directly run because this cannot be seen at the script editor.

When this function of `hoge` is run from other function, the script works.

#### About `var hogeNot = function hoge(x){return x;};`

In this case, the function of `hogeNot` cannot be seen at the script editor. But the function of `hoge` can be seen at the script editor. When the function of `hoge` is run by the script editor, an error like the function is not found occurs. At the above script, `i == "hoge"` is always `false`. But when `i == "hogeNot"` is used for the if statement, `hogeNot, function` is returned.

When this function of `hogeNot` is run from other function, the script works. But when this function of `hoge` is run from other function, an error occurs.

### Result:

From above situations, it is considered that in order to run with `google.script.run`, it is required to be able to directly run the function at the script editor. I think that this might be the specification of Google side.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer. Thanks to your answer, I could understand why couldn't call function in gs using google.script.run.

Comment: @容易いtayasui Thank you for your response.