# Google Apps Script (V8); why can't I use an object instance inside of onOpen?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, v8

Why can't I use an object instance inside of `onOpen`?

I'm experimenting with Google Apps Script using the new V8 runtime. I wrote some simple code which makes an instance of a class in the `onOpen` function and tries to associate a call to a method on that instance when I click on a menu entry.

When I click the associated menu entry, I get a "Script function not found" error. However, when I either create a global instance of the class or create a local instance in another function it works fine.

I tried logging the value of either a local instance or a global instance, but it only shows an empty object: `{}`.

Is this a bug, or some detail I missed while reading the documentation?

```
/** Application Class */
class Application {
    /**
     * ShowUi
     */
    showUi() {
        // const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Ui');
        const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
        const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.showModalDialog(html, 'User Interface');
    }
}

const global_app = new Application();

/** onOpen */
function onOpen() {
    const app = new Application();
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu('JSClass Example');

    console.log('app, local scope:');
    console.log(app);

    console.log('app, global scope');
    console.log(global_app);

    menu.addItem('Show UI (local)', 'app.showUi');
    menu.addItem('Show UI (global)', 'global_app.showUi');
    menu.addItem('Show UI (global fn)', 'showUi');

    menu.addToUi();
}

/** showUi */
function showUi() {
    const app3 = new Application();
    app3.showUi();
}
```

My bound Spreadsheet for this code is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u9XsQqUixSFg3or0OK3MdRDpN1S9uHmDSDMSdbDzxTU/edit?usp=sharing). I think you'll have to make a copy and click through some scary-looking warnings to actually run it, though.

Comment: When the function is run with the custom menu, it seems that the functions for executing are required to be the global. Because after the custom menu was installed with `onOpen()`, `app` of `const app = new Application()` is undefined when `app.showUi` is run with the custom menu. So the error occurs. On the other hand, `global_app.showUi` and `showUi` return the function. So no error occurs. For understanding this situation. for example, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59417714 If this is not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the `onOpen()` method is executed solely to populate the menu, **but not when a menu option is selected.**

When you select a menu item, it's performed in a fresh execution context and the state from within the `onOpen()` function from the previous execution (i.e. to populate the menu) is not carried over.

---

Another approach is using a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods), which you can call without having to create an instance of the class.

```
class Application {
    static showUi() {
        const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
        const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.showModalDialog(html, 'User Interface');
    }
}

function onOpen() {
    const app = new Application();
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu('V8 Menu Test');
    menu.addItem('Show UI', 'Application.showUi');
    menu.addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an installable onOpen trigger but it also works on a simple trigger.  I just wasn't paying attention to the menu when I first ran it.

```
/** Application Class */
class Application {
    /**
     * ShowUi
     */
    showUi() {
        // const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Ui');
        const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'User Interface');
    }
}

const global_app = new Application();

/** onOpen */
function openForMe() {
    const app = new Application();
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu('JSClass Example')
    .addItem('Show UI (local)', 'app.showUi')//this is still not working
    .addItem('Show UI (global)', 'global_app.showUi')
    .addItem('Show UI (global fn)', 'showUi')
    .addToUi();
}

/** showUi */
function showUi() {
    const app3 = new Application();
    app3.showUi();
}
```

This seems to be okay:

```
/** Application Class */
class Application {
     showUi() {
        const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'User Interface');
    }
}

const global_app = new Application();

/** onOpen */
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('JSClass Example')
  .addItem('Show UI (global)', 'global_app.showUi')
  .addItem('Show UI (global fn)', 'showUi')
  .addToUi();
}

/** showUi */
function showUi() {
    const app3 = new Application();
    app3.showUi();
}
```