# Trigger onOpen with an IF statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I want to run onOpen when only certain sheets are open, but not others in the spreadsheet to which the script is bound. The sheets that are needed all have names "Agent report - 'NameOfAgent'". Each agent report also has certain cells inside that can be used for the IF condition statement. Logically, I want to have this:

IF name of active sheet contains "Agent report" -> run script
ELSE do nothing

Alternatively,
IF in active sheet cell A2=="Role" -> run script
ELSE do nothing

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Won't the active sheet `onOpen` be always the first sheet? Also show what you've tried so far

Comment: It's not necessarily always the same sheet though.  Use a intermediate function and wrap your logic around that.

Comment: Questions that already were answered do not be changed in a way that it invalidates the current answers, instead you should post a new question. Considering this, I will revert the last edit made by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

`onOpen` will be executed when the owner or the editor open the spreadsheet no matter of what sheet was referred in the url parameters but you could include an `if` statement on i to control what is done when the condition is met.

```
/**
 * This will be executed always that the owner or an editor opens the spreadsheet
 *
 */
function onOpen(e){
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() === 'Agent report'){
    // This will be executen when the condition is true
    doSomething();
  } else {
    // This will be executen when the condition is false
    return; // This is actually not necessary as there isn't any statement after it.
  }
}

/**
 * Function to be called when the condition is met
 *
 */
function doSomething(){
  // do something
}
```

Related

- [Google Apps Script: Dynamically creating spreadsheet menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31539911/1595451)

Comment: Thank you, Rubén. I can't use "===" because "Agent Report" is not a unique name, but a common phrase in the names of several sheets where I'm trying to get the script executing every time such a sheet with "Agent Report" is activated.