# How to pass parameters to a menu function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to pass a variable when calling a function inside menu function:

```
function onOpen(){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addSubMenu
    (ui.createMenu('Save')
      .addItem('Save All', 'doSaveAll')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Save Grafics (Trade - Options - BTC - Termo - Future -  Fund)', 'doSaveSheets')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Save Trade',   'doSaveSheet("Trade")')
      .addItem('Save Options', 'doSaveSheet("Opções")')
      .addItem('Save BTC',     'doSaveSheet("BTC")')
      .addItem('Save Termo',   'doSaveSheet("Termo")')
      .addItem('Save Future',  'doSaveSheet("Future")')
      .addItem('Save Fund',    'doSaveSheet("Fund")')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Save Proventos','doSaveProventos')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Save Balanço (BLC - DRE - FLC - DVA)','doSaveDatas')
    //....
    )
    .addToUi();
};
```

When I try from  menu to use Trade, I get error

```
Função de script não encontrada: doSaveSheet("Trade")
```

I guess it would be something like

```
Function script was not found: doSaveSheet("Trade")
```

Is there a way from menu to call that function with that variable or do I need to workaround with something like:

```
function menuSaveTrade() {
  doSaveSheet('Trade');
}

      .addItem('Save Trade',   'menuSaveTrade()')
```

That would defeat the purpose of having function structured like this:

```
function doSaveSheets() 
{
  const sheetNames = ['Trade', 'Opções', 'BTC', 'Termo', 'Future', 'Fund'];
  
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => 
  {
    try 
    {
      doSaveSheet(sheetName);
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
      console.error(`Error saving sheet ${sheetName}:`, error);
    }
  });
}

function doSaveSheet(sheetName) 
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss_t = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);                                 // ss_s = target spreadsheet
  const ss_c = ss.getSheetByName('Config');                                  // ss_c = config spreadsheet

  Utilities.sleep(2500); // 2,5 secs

  console.log('Save:', sheetName);

  if (sheetName === 'Trade') 
  {
      var C2_ = ss_t.getRange('C2').getValue();  

      var Proventos = ss_c.getRange(ENP).getDisplayValue();        // ENP = Enable Proventos
      var Save = ss_c.getRange(STR).getDisplayValue();             // STR = Save to Trade 

    const ss_p = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Prov');

      var B3_ = ss_p.getRange('B3').getDisplayValue();  

    if( ( B3_ == "Proventos" || Proventos != "TRUE" ) && ( C2_ > 0 ) )  // check if error
    {
      processSaveSheet(ss_t, sheetName, Save) 

      doExportSheet(sheetName)                                     // Special case to export alone
    }

  doCheck(sheetName)
  }
//.......
}
```

Those functions work, that isn't the problem. I am just having trouble with the menu, as I couldn't find a way to make it work.

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to a menu function.

Comment: yea after many attempts i feared that, so im  going to create a bunch o dummy  functions instead to be used on menu, reply as an answer so i can set that

Comment: Since a person has to click on the menu's how about using a custom dialog that has all of the parameters builtin as select elements.  Perhaps that way you can minimise the number of functions.

Comment: Here's a simple dialog I did yesterday

Comment: did you forget  to link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76731190/7215091

Comment: i will  play around with it,  cos ive never did it, but in this case i just created a bunch of dummy functions, menu is there just in case,  to not open app script,   but everything is triggered and automated anyway ,  actually around 250 Spreadsheets,  im updating the template to redo all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, if you want to create the custom menu using `doSaveSheet(sheetName)` with the arguments of `['Trade', 'Opções', 'BTC', 'Termo', 'Future', 'Fund']`, how about the following workaround?

In this workaround, the custom menu is dynamically created. This workaround referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59417714).

When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please reopen Google Spreadsheet. By this, the custom menu is created.

```js
setCustomMenu(); // In this workaround, please don't remove this line.
function onOpen() { } // In this workaround, please don't remove this line.

function setCustomMenu() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu');
  var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Save')
    .addItem('Save All', 'doSaveAll')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Save Grafics (Trade - Options - BTC - Termo - Future -  Fund)', 'doSaveSheets')
    .addSeparator();
  var obj = [ // This is from your showing script.
    { name: 'Save Trade', arg: 'Trade' },
    { name: 'Save Options', arg: 'Opções' },
    { name: 'Save BTC', arg: 'BTC' },
    { name: 'Save Termo', arg: 'Termo' },
    { name: 'Save Future', arg: 'Future' },
    { name: 'Save Fund', arg: 'Fund' },
  ];
  obj.forEach(({ name, arg }, i) => {
    var fn = `func${i}`;
    this[fn] = function (arg) {
      return function () { return doSaveSheet(arg) };
    }(arg);
    subMenu.addItem(name, fn);
  });
  subMenu.addSeparator()
    .addItem('Save Proventos', 'doSaveProventos')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Save Balanço (BLC - DRE - FLC - DVA)', 'doSaveDatas')
  //...
  menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
}

function doSaveSheets() {

  // Please replace this script with your actual script of doSaveSheets().

}

function doSaveSheet(sheetName) {

  Browser.msgBox(sheetName);
  // Please replace this script with your actual script of doSaveSheet(sheetName).

}
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is tested, the following result is obtained. In this test, `Browser.msgBox(sheetName);` is run. You can see that the function `doSaveSheet(sheetName)` is run with each argument.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Dynamically creating spreadsheet menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31539911)

Comment: works just great, many thanks i couldn't do that, but i can manage to adapt the rest of the code,  really appreciate

Comment: menu works perfectly, but if i try to run any function from within spreadsheet like ```=getSheetID()```  that returns getId(),  i get ```Error
Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 5). ```Which is   ```var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();``` from your exemple

Comment: @Bruno Carvalho About your new issue of `menu works perfectly, but if i try to run any function from within spreadsheet like =getSheetID() that returns getId(), i get Error Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 5). Which is var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); from your exemple`, unfortunately, this script cannot be used with the custom function. I have to deeply apologize for this specification of Google side.